# What is the minimum gigabit ethernet latency I can expect?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, latency

I have 2 Lenovo ThinkPads running Ubuntu with a 1 meter ethernet cable between them, both having standard Intel Ethernet adapters.

The `ping` between the two is about `300 us` (microseconds).

This seems quite high; why is it? I have read that 1 GbE can typically achieve 40 us latency.

Is this the minimum latency I can expect, or is there software tuning I can perform to reduce this latency? What is the bottleneck? Is it Linux? On [this gamer web site for Windows](http://www.pcgamer.com/motherboards-with-killer-network-adapters-arent-worth-your-money/) the tool in the screenshot seems to suggest 40 us latency in most cases.

Comment: Many, possibilities.  Need to know specs.  If you don't have a fast enough CPU and enough RAM it could slow it down.  Which Ubuntu if it has an old kernel that also could impact it.  **uname -r** If you don't have a 4.x kernel upgrade.

Comment: @cybernard ThinkPad T440, Ubuntu 16.04's kernel (which is a 4.4). There is no CPU usage apparent from the `ping` (it would indeed suprise me if `ping` exhausted my CPU or RAM).

Comment: Not ping exhausting your CPU, but something else using 99% of the CPU and then you run ping at the same time.

Comment: @cybernard Ah OK -- both machines are completely idle and have 7 GB of free RAM.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think there's anything wrong with the machines. I've seen this kind of roughly-half-a-millisecond-ethernet-ping between many devices already. I'm just wondering why it is this high, in general. I'm hoping it is an unfortunate default in Linux.

Comment: do you have hardware offloading enabled?

Comment: ethtool  --show-offload eth0    You just have to test it both ways on and off on both machines.  ethtool  --offload eth0 rx on tx on  also ethtool  --offload eth0 gso on tso on

Comment: @cybernard Unfortunately none of these offloading changes have made any difference to my `ping`.

Comment: Given no answers, I have [reposted this question at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/874143/what-is-the-minimum-gigabit-ethernet-latency-i-can-expect), where more people familiar with network tuning might be watching. Unfortunately I can't move it there instead of reposting because I don't have enough reputation here.